Analyzing disk space
I was trying to check my disk space. For that I used 2 different commands, and get 2 different results:

Can you explain this dicrepancy considering both commands are for the same purpose?

Ubuntu 18.04 LTS reached End of Standard Support last year, and is thus off-topic on this site.  You can use ESM/Pro support options (cost maybe involved) if you wish but community support (such as this site) no longer exists, though SE Unix & Linux allow all Ubuntu questions too.  Please see https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic or Canonical who provide ESM/Pro services.
